# Increment views table with just 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a way to increment a views table for some content, or if it doesn't exist add the first view without running 2 queries. Here's my current code that works.

```
function increment_views($id = null) {

  if ($id !== NULL) {
    $record = array('id' => $id, 'views' => 'views+1');
    // check exists
    $query = $this->db->get_where('views', array('id' => $id), 1, 0);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
      // if !exists, insert
        $db_view_data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'views' => '1'
        );
        $this->db->insert('views', $db_view_data);
    } else {
      // A record does exist, update it.
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->set('views', 'views+1', false);
      $this->db->update('views');

    }
    // check it worked
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using on duplicate key as follows :

```
$query = "INSERT into views(id,views)values($id,1) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I did do that previously, but it errored if there was no view value yet, as in, if some content was just added it wouldn't have any views yet to update.

Comment: Please check with my new query. Updated :)

Comment: You should add that this works only if `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY`.

Comment: @ypercube sorry i missed to tell that point.. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what DB wrapper you are using, however, you basically want to execute the following single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = ...;
```